# Using XML namespaces

Tags: xml, namespaces

While searching Web I encountered many examples of using namespaces in XML files. They mostly have this form:

```
<d:student xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'>
  <d:id>3235329</d:id>
  <d:name>Jeff Smith</d:name>
  <d:language>C#</d:language>
  <d:rating>9.5</d:rating>
</d:student>
```

(this is example taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302166.aspx)

This line:

```
<d:student xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'>
```

troubles me, pretty much because every example looks like this. Can it have a form of

```
<student xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'>
```

So here I am declaring the same namespace identified by the same URI, but i don't want node where declaration is to have namespace. Is it correct? Long story short: is `just xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'` a valid declaration for `d:` namespace?

Answer (score 1):

`xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'` will declare the `d` namespace for that elements and all its descendants.

It will not make the element come from that namespace if it lacks `d:` on the tag name. That will still use the default namespace.

i.e.

```
<foo xmlns="http://example.com/1">
    <bar xmlns:x="http://example.com/2">
        <x:baz />
    </bar>
</foo>
```

`foo` comes from `/1`. `bar` comes from `/1`. `baz` comes from `/2`.

Answer (score 0):

`d` ist not the namespace but an alias for it (that is usable as a prefix). The namespace is still `http://www.develop.com/student`.

`<d:student xmlns:d='http://www.develop.com/student'/>` can be read as `{http://www.develop.com/student}:student`.

It is possible to define a default namespace for elements without a prefix using the xmlns attribute. So `<student xmlns='http://www.develop.com/student'/>` can be read as `{http://www.develop.com/student}:student`, too.

The DOM keeps the namespace and the localname in separate properties of the node objects actually. The `{namespace}:localname` syntax is often used for debug outputs.

A namspace deifnition is always valid for the element node it is defined on and all its descendants (unless it is overwritten in a descendant).

Attribute nodes do not use the default namespace definition. Attributes without a prefix are always in the "empty" namespace.

Here is an example that doesn't use prefixes.

```
<student xmlns="http://www.develop.com/student">
  <id>3235329</id>
  <name>Jeff Smith</name>
  <description type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/">
      ...
    </div>
  </description>
</student>
```

The node names in the example (with resolved namespaces) are:

- `{http://www.develop.com/student}:student`
- `{http://www.develop.com/student}:id`
- `{http://www.develop.com/student}:name`
- `{}:type`
- `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/}:div`